# Fresnel Integral

Tags: integration

Does someone know how they go from the left side to the right side?

$$\left(\int_{0}^{R}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx\right)^2 = \iint_{[0,R]^2} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,dx\,dy $$

Thanks.

Comment: Ever heard of Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @OpenBall No :p, I'm a first-year university student :p

Comment: I guess $G$ is $[0,R]^2$, and the diagram is quite irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll delete the diagram

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^R e^{-x^2/2}\,dx&=\sqrt{\int_0^R e^{-x^2/2}\,dx\,\int_0^R e^{-y^2/2}\,dy}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\int_0^R\int_0^R e^{-x^2/2}e^{-y^2/2}\,dx\,dy}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\int_0^R\int_0^R e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,dx\,dy}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why the square roots?

Comment: @Bernard The left-hand side has not been squared.

Comment: I mean, in the O.P.'s question, it *is* squared.

Comment: @Bernard I'm starting with the integral that I presume the OP is interested in evaluating.  That's all really.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the [Gaussian integral calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates)
$$
\left(\int_0^Re^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx\right)^2=
\int_0^Re^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx\cdot \int_0^Re^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\,dy=
\int_0^R\int_0^Re^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\,dx\,dy=\iint_{[0,R]\times[0,R]}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\,dxdy.
$$